# How do I write a Dynamic LINQ query and have Orderby [Sort Direction]

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

I would like to write a LINQ query similar to this SQL query:

**Select ID, Title, Description, Date From SomeTable**

And then add an **'OrderBy'** and **'Ascending/Descending'** Dynamically.

I need this to add a sort functionality on a gridview, whose datasource is this linq query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write your own `SortBy` extension method that takes a `SortDirection`.

```
public enum SortDirection { Ascending, Descending }

public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> SortBy<TSource, TKey>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        SortDirection sortDirection,
        Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        switch (sortDirection)
        {
            case SortDirection.Ascending:
                return source.OrderBy(keySelector);
            case SortDirection.Descending:
                return source.OrderByDescending(keySelector);
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var sortDirection = Sort.Descending; // this could be set dynamically at runtime
var sorted = new[] { 1, 2, 3 }.SortBy(SortDirection.Descending, x => x);
```

Comment: Is there any way to not have to use the switch statement?

Comment: @MikeMurphy, What is the reason for avoiding the switch statement?

Comment: my perception is that it seems "messy". i find it hard to believe there isnt a cleaner or more flexible way. i have no basis for my perception.

Comment: I think the problem is that the LINQ API is "messy"--it forces you to use a different function for ascending vs. descending sorts. If you don't know the sort direction at compile time, you need some sort of conditional to chose `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending`. The point of creating an extension method is to at least isolate the messiness. There are certainly different ways to do conditional logic, such as an if statement, conditional (?:) operator, or dictionary, but none of them are necessarily cleaner. I chose a case statement because I think it's readable and makes intent clear.

Comment: @MikeMurphy, meant to address the above comment to you.